# Match and extract href info using regex

Tags: swift, regex, href

I am trying to make a regex that match and extract href link information in more than one case, for example both with double, single and no quotation mark in Swift.

```
A regex to match href and extract info <a href=https://www.google.com>Google</a>.
<a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a> 
<a href='https://www.google.com'>Google</a>
```

I have found this regex, but it only works with double quotation:

```
<a href="([^"]+)">([^<]+)<\/a>
```

Result:

```
Match 1: <a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>
Group 1: https://www.google.com
Group 2: Google
```

What I want is to detect all of the three ways that I provided with the sample text.

Note: I know that regex shouldn't be used for parsing HTML, but I am using it for a very small use case so it's fine.

Comment: `<a href=('[^']+'|"[^"]+"|[^ '">]+)`. You are not revealing which regex variant you are using so trimming the quotes left as an exercise. If you have Perl-compatible, it's not hard to exclude them from the actual match.

Comment: @tripleee I am using the on in http://regex101.com/, I tried the one you provided, but it's not what I exactly want, I wan't the be able to match all href tag, and extract url and title to replace them with markdown syntax to show the link with title.

Comment: You will want to read the [tag:regex] tag guidance and [edit] your question accordingly. Which tool or language are you using?

Comment: @tripleee Done. I am using Swift language.

Comment: Swift allows for non-grouping parentheses, so you can say `<a href=(?:'([^']+)'|"([^"]+)"|)[^ '">]+)).*>([^<>]+)</a>` and then check whether `$1`, `$2`, or `$3` is non-empty, and then adjust which group you pull out depending on that. But I don't know the language so leave it up to someone else to take it from there.

Comment: Side note `let attrStr = try! NSAttributedString(htmlString: str)` seems to parse the 3 links, so you could use it maybe?

Comment: @tripleee Thank you, I tired the one you provided but it has two unmatched parenthesis. Could you check it again please.

Comment: @Larme Yes I know, but I don't want to use NSAttributedString because styling it will be another problem, it doesn't follow system dark/light mode...etc.

Comment: Sorry, fat fingered it, `<a href=(?:'([^']+)'|"([^"]+)"|([^ '">]+)).*>([^<>]+)</a>` obviously

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming there is no other attribute in anchor tags in the file you wish to parse, you can use the following regex : `/<a href=('|"|)([^'">]+)\1>([^<]+)<\/a>/$2 $3/gm`.

It first captures either single quote, double quote or nothing and then `\1` recalls that capturing group, [watch it live here on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/TTOwCi/1).

Answer (score 0):

Answer is already in comments but posting this since the approach is bit different.

In `swift 5.7+` & `iOS 16+`  u can use [`regexBuilder`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/regexbuilder) for this.

```
import RegexBuilder


var link1 = "A regex to match href and extract info <a href=https://www.google.com>Google</a>."
var link2 = "<a href='\"https://www.google.com\">Google</a>"
var link3 = "<a href='https://www.google.com'>Google</a>"

let regex = Regex {
    Capture {
        "https://www."
        ZeroOrMore(.word)
        "."
        ZeroOrMore(.word)
    }

}

if let result1 = try? regex.firstMatch(in: link1) {
    print("link: \(result1.output.1)")
}

if let result2 = try? regex.firstMatch(in: link2) {
    print("link: \(result2.output.1)")
}

if let result3 = try? regex.firstMatch(in: link3) {
    print("link: \(result3.output.1)")
}
```

This work well for the above 3 provided strings. But depend on the scenarios u might need to change the implementation.